# Find a map that glues together the pairs $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, equivalence-relations

I need to find a linear mapping from the  $xy$ plane to the $x'y'$ plane  such that the respective coordinates are related like this:

- they remain in place if the coordinate are equal $(x',y')=(x,y)$, if $x=y$
- if  $x \neq  y$    Both $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ must be mapped to $(x,y)$  with $y \geq x$
  so the mapping should do this point by point, "glueing together" the pairs  $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$.
  $(x',y')=F(x,y)=(f1(x,y),f2(x,y))$, what could $f1$ and $f2$ be and how to figure it out?
  Any idea?

[image]

Comment: The image of a linear mapping from the plane is either a plane, a line, or a point.  Since your intended image is a half-plane, there is no such linear mapping.

Comment: don't know if it is linear, but the answer is actually the one  below, is the procedure that takes to it what I am interested in.

Comment: You require to "find a linear mapping".  There is no such thing meeting the given constraints.  The answer below does not supply a linear mapping.  At the very least, your Question should be altered to admit the answer you seem to accept.

Comment: how to word it then?

Comment: this was actually part of a question in topology, going from an euclidean two dimensional space to the topological subspace restricted to the described  half plane

Comment: It is not a homeomorphism, nor an isometry.  It is an isotopy and a homotopy.  It is an immersion, but not an embedding.  How to word it depends on what types of map you are discussing.  Most generally, "a continuous map", although frequently, continuity is assumed in topological maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map you are describing is uniquely defined, so all you need to do is write it down. There are several ways you can do this, but they will all describe the same map.

1. The first way is the way you described it in the question. It's perfectly fine, and anyone reading what you wrote can calculate $F(x,y)$ for any particular pair $(x,y)$. That is, what you did is rigorous enough to need no other work.
2. If you want a more symbolic way of writing, you can write exactly what you wrote with symbols, like so:$$F(x,y)=\begin{cases}(x, y)&\text{ if } y\geq x\\ (y,x) &\text{ if } y < x\end{cases}$$
   which is just exactly what you wrote, written in fewer words and more symbols.
3. If you want a nice short way of writing what you wrote, then you can also write $$F(x, y) = (\min(x,y), \max(x,y)),$$ which also means the same thing.

---

Which of the three options is the best? In my honest opinion, **none of them**. Each is best for a particular scenario.

The first is great if you are talking about the map $F$. With no annoying symbols to decipher, it is the description that needs the least amount of time for people to understand, and is also the only one that will not scare away a non-mathematical crowd.

The second is great because it is easy to see what is happening, to a mind accustomed to some mathematical symbols.

The third is great because it's shortest, but to me, it takes a little more time to understand what exactly the map does.

---

How do you get to these descriptions? Well, you got to the first description just fine. The second is just writing the same thing as the first, but in symbols.

The third, well, the map $F$ takes $(x,y)$, and flips the members of the pair if $x$ is greater than $y$. In other words, it always returns the smaller of the values $(x,y)$ in the first position, and the bigger of the two values on the second position. Well, "the smaller of the two values" is simply $\min(x,y)$, and the bigger is $\max(x,y)$...

Comment: Nice, that is the answer i was given in my lecture notes, but I actually wanted to know how to figure it out, like some procedure or hint that takes me to it

Comment: I need it an analytical expresion like that one because then I have to prove continuity, surjectivity, injectivity in a topological sense, to study the quotient function, but they just start out the solution with the map, like magic. I'd like to know how to figure it out

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver I greatly expanded my answer.

Comment: Yes, but you must address the fact that $F$ is *not* a linear map (for example, the image of a midpoint is not the midpoint of their images)

Comment: what should I call this? they are saying it's not a linear mapping, but I know there is an expression for mina and max using the absolute value, for the max it is $max(x,y)=1/2( (x+y)+|x-y|) and a similar one for the min, aren't this linear combinations after getting rid of the absolute value?

Comment: But the issue is that you have 2 distinct expressions according to the sign of $x-y$... Btw, I hadn't read your answer because you forgot to write @name

Answer (score 0):

It's not a *linear* function.

The given definition is exhaustive, and in formulas it's
$$F(x,y) =(\min(x, y), \ \max(x, y))\,. $$

Comment: what do you mean with exhaustive?

Comment: I mean it's well defined for all possible cases, and you don't necessarily need a closed formula to work with $F$.